# Blade does not seem to work (maybe "extends")

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I know it's not a specific question, but that's because it's the only info I have about my problem.
For some reason, my blade templates do not seem to work.

Folder structure:
resources / views / layouts / master.blade.php
resources / views / child.blade.php

master.blade.php:

```
<p>Some content here</p>
@yield('content')
<p>Some additional content here</p>
```

child.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')
<p>This is the user content</p>
@endsection
```

My expectations are:
Some content here
This is the user content
Some additional content here

What I get is:
Some content here
Some additional content here

So my content section is not showing up at all.

I am using Laracast and Laravel v5.7.8
I also set up a new laravel application in different versions (5.1.* - 5.7.8) but in every new application it didn't work.

I think it can't be an issue with my files. Let me tell you why:
The `welcome.blade.php` shows a login button if `Route::has('login')`.
If I add a login route it doesn't show aswell and I didn't edit the welcome page. And it does not work in new laravel applications aswell.

I don't got a clue why this is...

Thanks for any help.
And yes, I've done my research for a couple of hours now.

Comment: Is your problem that all three lines of text are not showing up, or is it that they are out of order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it now. The routes where wrong and nothing with my files.
What I did was:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
   return view('master');
});
```

This is of course wrong and what it should be is:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
   return view('child');
});
```

I've looked through the files many times and didn't notice it...
It's just some of those days :D.
Still, thanks to anyone who tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

For the order you mentioned you just need to move your `yield` below the paragraph, like this:

```
<p>Some content here</p>
<p>Some additional content here</p>
@yield('content')
```

Notice how `@yield` is the below these 2 paragraphs, with this you get the desired output

Comment: Sorry I messed something up in my question. I edited my question.
My problem is that @yield('content') is not showing up at all.